# Opposite of "granular"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, business-language, metaphors, neologisms

What is the opposite of "granular" in the following usage?

> **granularity**
>
> The level of detail considered in a model or decision making process.
>   The greater the granularity, the deeper the level of detail.
>   Granularity is usually used to characterize the scale or level of
>   detail in a set of data.
>
> http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/granularity.html

I'm looking for something tropologically parallel, so not "generalized," "basic," or the like.

Comment: Meriam Webster suggests the following "near antonyms": *buttery, smooth, velvety
filtered, levigated, refined
close-grained, comminuted, ground, micronized, milled, mulled, pestled, pulverized, reduced, triturated*

Comment: Can you suggest a sentence you want this word to be in?  From this OP, I can't decide if you would use "aggregate" or "30000 foot view"

Comment: Granularity is a gradable attribute. Granularity  can be fine or coarse which are opposites.  But if an object has no granularity at all then it might be completely smooth or homogenous.

Comment: You specify 'granular' but define 'granularity'. It is not always obvious how the adjective relates to the noun, and we need an example sentence showing the sense you have in mind, from a reasonably authoritative source.

Comment: Did you mean Topologically? One problem is that granularity does not mean fine detail, but the level of detail - fine or coarse. Like asking for more decorum does not mean more quiet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the sense is close to the source of the granular metaphor from the real world, the group of actual grains (of sand) in concrete and geology is [aggregate](https://www.britannica.com/technology/aggregate), and I understand it means the opposite thing when you say you will look at X at the most granular level, and you will look at X in the aggregate.

If the sense of granularity is within the business context of "the opposite of detail oriented", the [big picture](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big%20picture), [vision](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/vision-statement.html) and [30,000 foot view](https://askthemanager.com/2008/11/the-25-most-annoying-business-phrases/#.XC0EFVxKiUk) are applicable MBA buzzwords.

Answer (score 3):

In the context, I'd use coarse or coarseness. The granularity you refer to implies levels of fine detail in the data. Coarseness implies increasing levels of 'lower detail' using similar language.

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary reference for the chosen word(s).

Answer (score 2):

In this use case I would apply "holistic".

> **Holistic**
> *adjective*
>
> Philosophy
> 1 Characterized by the belief that the parts of something are intimately interconnected and explicable only by reference to the whole.
>
> Example sentences
>
> - ‘Moreover, holistic method has proved useful in the hard sciences, for example in the geological theory of plate tectonics.’
> - ‘If so, a paradigm shift to the holistic approach might be managed.’
> - ‘These two books bring a holistic approach to the analysis of transport and transport networks.’
> - ‘We will all need to get beyond our individual narrow interests and begin to develop a holistic solution that works for everyone.’
> - ‘I think where Chaos and Complexity theory are really going, is, a holistic understanding of the universe.’
>
> 1.1  Medicine
> Characterized by the treatment of the whole person, taking into account mental and social factors, rather than just the symptoms of a disease.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/holistic

Answer (score -1):

Granularity in a generalized business context may not have an antonym, but I did find this [antonym of granularity](https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/granularity), which is a good antonym.

This [source](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/granularity/antonyms) also has a ton of antonyms, but not the one you are looking for, I believe.